Programatically scale content (Stimulsoft Reports.NET)
Can you programatically call the scale content to a size in code as opposed to having to select it from the viewer-> page size?

I wrote the following commands and expected the report.RenderedPages[i] variable to have a ScaleContent property, but it doesn't :
report.Render();
for (int i = 0; i < report.RenderedPages.Count; i++)
{
    report.RenderedPages[i].PaperSize = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.B5JisRotated;
    report.RenderedPages[i].PageWidth = 18.3;
    report.RenderedPages[i].PageHeight = 25.6;
    report.RenderedPages[i].Margins = new Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiMargins(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5);
    report.RenderedPages[i].ScaleContent = true;
}

